# How can I solve the post installation error for gatsby in windows?

Tags: gatsby

I am using Windows operating system and I installed gatsby cli by using the following command:

npm i -g gatsby-cli

After installation, I tried running the following command in order to start with new project in gatsby

gatsby new gatsbyBootcamp https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world

But I got the following error after running the above command

```
C:\Users\Ruchit Sherathiya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\init-starter.js:117
  } catch {
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ruchit Sherathiya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\create-cli.js:28:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your run the command as super?

Comment: I would uninstall the gatsby cli and try the install again... If it still doesn't work, try installing a different npm module and testing that, to see if npm is broken, otherwise, it is something with the gatsbycli, or your computer